# Python 2.7 - как получить значение функции, которая используется в Threading.Timer?

Tags: python-2.7

Пытаюсь на простой программе решить следующую задачу: 
Есть 2 потока. Первый поток должен быть запущен постоянно (в течение жизни программы), второй поток нужно запускать через определенные промежутки времени, при этом в переменную result нужно сохранить значение функции.
Знаю что можно использовать очередь Queue, но это работает для класса Thread, а у меня используется Timer. 
Есть ли еще варианты запуска функции по таймеру с одновременным получением и сохранением значения функции в переменную result?

```py
from threading import Thread, Timer

def func1():
    print "Hello"


def func2(q):
    x = 'True'
    print "Hi"
    return x

def main():

    thread1 = Thread(target=func1())
    thread1.start()

    thread2 = Timer(5.0, func2)
    thread2.start()

    result = thread2 # сюда нужно передать значение функции func2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```